# How to use vector(c++) in go?

Tags: c++, stl, go

Now I try to use C++ in go,but the data in C++ are some STL(like vector, map, list).

Maybe SWIG can help me, but I'm looking for other way to finish it.

Is that possible?

I appreciate any help and suggest.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're required to use a vector?

Comment: As @SimonWhitehead said - what are you trying to achieve? Go has all these containers implemented in the native library as maps and slices, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: The data a vector refers to is a plain array; you could potentially represent as a Go slice by getting a pointer to the first item and the length/capacity and  creating a SliceHeader object (see "turning C arrays into Go slices" at https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo). Note that as with native Go slices, you'd have to update the slice header after reslicing/reallocating. Maps and lists require more code to use; you might write functions to access them on the C++ side and use those *functions* from the Go side. It's a broad question: many solutions, none of them easy.